# golang same string of sha1 representation but different byte slices produced

Tags: go, sha1

I'm going crazy here..
here is a sample test func

https://play.golang.org/p/CZO3rH2EErT

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    sha1slice := []byte{165, 75, 200, 121, 106, 64, 196, 203, 143, 25, 88, 22, 63, 8, 234, 244, 174, 211, 98, 152}
    sha1Str := string(sha1slice)

    sigStr := "�K�yj@�ˏX?����b�"
    sigSlice := []byte(sigStr)

    fmt.Println("sha1 data:")
    fmt.Println(sha1slice)
    fmt.Println(sha1Str)
    fmt.Println("sig Data:")
    fmt.Println(sigStr)
    fmt.Println(sigSlice)
}
```

here is the output

```
sha1 data:
[165 75 200 121 106 64 196 203 143 25 88 22 63 8 234 244 174 211 98 152]
�K�yj@�ˏX?����b�
sig Data:
�K�yj@�ˏX?����b�
[239 191 189 75 239 191 189 121 106 64 239 191 189 203 143 25 88 22 63 8 239 191 189 239 191 189 239 191 189 239 191 189 98 239 191 189]
```

the story here is that im calculating a sha1 hash which produces the byte array `sha1slice` 20 byte length.

the original signature is given to me as a string during input.
now i know that the sha1 is the correct one and it indeed produces the same string but check the byte array of the original signature and it does not match the sha1 byte array.

Im loosing it.. how come the same string representation have different byte array representations in this code?

is there some missing encoding param that is set on a string? how does go handle that ?

Comment: This is most likely an encoding issue. SHA1 contains "random" bytes, and a `string` in Go is the UTF-8 encoded sequence of the text.  Your second output contains lots of `239 191 189` sub-sequences, which is `ef bf bd` in hex, which is the UTF-8 encoded sequence of the unicode value `0xFEFF`. This is the Unicode replacement character which is used if invalid UTF-8 sequences are detected in strings. In short: your input Go string does not represent the same byte data as the SHA1 checkshum.

Comment: That strings that "look" the same have different byte representations in UTF-8 is not unusual at all: https://blog.golang.org/normalization. Don't get hung up on that. Just stick to byte slices if you're not dealing with text; don't convert hashes to strings or try to specify the raw signature value as a string literal. You can use [hex.Dump](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#Dump), for instance, if you want to inspect the bytes.

Comment: the problem is that this signature is sent to me via query string .. :\and this is the text I receive .. and i should teat it as a valid signature... (I know right ?! )

Comment: If the SHA1 checksum is passed as "the actual bytes" as a string... It shoudl probably go through "convert it to hex" before being sent, to ensure it won't be corrupted during transmission.

Comment: @icza indeed i see what you mean every character that is above 127 is encoded as the sequence `239 191 189` which is the non break zero with character in UTF-8 ..
any idea how i can parse the diamond characters with their correct value ? or does it mean the information got lost when it was converted to string by the sender...

Comment: @Vatine you are absolutely correct but unfortunately i have no control over this part and just have to make due with what i receive in QS :\

Comment: @Mortalus If you have that Go string value, the information is already lost. Try to track back how you obtain that Go string value.

Comment: The hash value was converted to Unicode code points assuming that the hash value is valid UTF-8 byte sequence and converted back to UTF-8.  Because hash values are not in general valid UTF-8 sequences, this is a lossy operation.  More than one sequence of input bytes can produce the same output bytes in this operation.  If you are debugging by examining output on your terminal, then the problem might be caused by conversions in your terminal.  Print strings  with %q format verb to avoid this problem.  It will helpful if you can show us the %q output.

Comment: If the problem is with the client and you cannot change the client, then use `string([]rune(string(hash)))` to replicate the problem conversion.

Comment: The query string should be percent-encoded, else it's not a valid HTTP request. It's unusual but should work. Just convert to []byte ASAP. Add the relevant handler code to the question.